# virtual web browser submit using HtmlUnit + Java

Tags: java, submit, htmlunit

I'm trying to sign in to yahoo.com using [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/). But it doesn't work when my program trying to click "Sign In" button. My code is:

```
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlForm;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlSubmitInput;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlTextInput;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.BrowserVersion;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.Page;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.RefreshHandler;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

public class MyBrowser {

    public void homePage() throws Exception {


        WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_3_6);
        webClient.setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);

        webClient.setRefreshHandler(new RefreshHandler() {
            public void handleRefresh(Page page, URL url, int arg) throws IOException {
                System.out.println("handleRefresh");
            }

        });

        HtmlPage page = (HtmlPage) webClient.getPage("https://login.yahoo.com/config/login?.src=fpctx&.intl=us&.done=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.yahoo.com%2F");
        HtmlForm form = page.getFormByName("login_form");

        form.getInputByName("login").setValueAttribute("@@@@@@");  // works OK
        form.getInputByName("passwd").setValueAttribute("@@@@@@"); // works OK
        page = (HtmlPage) form.getInputByValue("Sign In").click(); // doesn't work

        webClient.closeAllWindows();
    }

}
```

Error:

```
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ElementNotFoundException: elementName=[input] attributeName=[value] attributeValue=[Sign In]
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlForm.getInputByValue(HtmlForm.java:737)
```

Form is:

```
<form method="post" action="https://login.yahoo.com/config/login?" autocomplete="" name="login_form" onsubmit="return hash2(this)">
    ...
    <div id="submit">
        <button type="submit" id=".save" name=".save" class="primaryCta" tabindex="5"> Sign In </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do know nothing about HtmlUnit, but from the error message it looks like the it searches for some element with a `value` attribute, and your button has no such attribute. Maybe `byName` or such? And it is not a `<input>` element, but a `<button>` element, so maybe something like [`getButtonByName(".save")`](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/HtmlForm.html#getButtonByName%28java.lang.String%29)?

Edit: I found the Javadoc, and seems I guessed the method name right :-p

Comment: `page = (HtmlPage) form.getButtonByName(".save").getEnclosingForm().click();`

Now I should get other page (page after button click) but in this case page is the same.

Comment: Why do you click the form and not the button?

Comment: Now my code is `HtmlButton signInButton = liginForm.getButtonByName(".save");
        HtmlPage nextPage = (HtmlPage) signInButton.click();` and this works but throws very large number of various exceptions. Further work is not affected these exceptions but the program looks incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

The Yahoo login form submit button has a name specification, not a value specification.  You need to get the input by name.  I suggest that you change:

```
page = (HtmlPage) form.getInputByValue("Sign In").click();
```

...to...

```
page = (HtmlPage) form.getInputByName("Sign In").click();
```

Comment: Keep the code in `code` blocks. See the help or read the FAQ about how to do it.